# Python 2.7 - Iterating Over Elements in 2 Different Lists, Why Each One Print Different Format

Tags: regex, list, python-2.7, for-loop

In my newbie experimenting and trying to write lots of little scripts and learn; I bumped into this puzzlement:

```
import re

nouns = ['bacon', 'cheese', 'eggs', 'milk']
article = []

def list_in_list(list1, list2):
    for list_1_element in list1:
        print list_1_element
    for list_2_element in list2:
        print list_2_element


with open('test_sentence.txt', 'r') as input_f:
    for line in input_f:
        article.append(re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;:]", line))
        list_in_list(article, nouns)
```

Here is the contents of the test_sentence.txt:

```
I need to go shopping today and some of the things I need to buy are bacon, cheese and eggs. I also need to buy something with a comma in it, such as milk, cheese, and bacon.
```

What I don't understand is why `print list_1_element` actually prints the whole 'list1' list such as `['I', 'need', 'to', 'go'.............]`.  And the the `print list_2_element` actually prints each element of that list on a new line, as I would expect.

So why the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

article.append([some list]) appends the list as one item

article.extend([some list]) would append each item in some list to the article list

Comment: Thanks for that. My eye was not keen enough to notice that the article list created started with 2 `[[` and ending in 2 `]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `article` is a list containing a single item. You add one list of lists per line, and you have one line.